Mac Studio doesn't recognize monitors' HDR or properly output to it
I have a new Mac Studio and am having troubles with it and my monitors' HDR. How do I force it to recognize and properly output an HDR signal?
Before I got the Mac Studio I had both of these monitors connected to a PC with an Nvidia GTX 1080 Ti which was using them at their full resolution, frame rate, and HDR - so they definitely do actually support it. It connected to the left monitor via DisplayPort and the right via HDMI.
My right monitor is the ViewSonic VP2785 (4K60, HDR, AdobeRGB). It has DisplayPort and HDMI inputs.
When I connect it via HDMI, I do not get an HDR option in Settings. I can set resolution (which is "More Space" i.e. native), color profile (AdobeRGB), refresh rate (60 Hz), and rotation (standard).
When I connect it with a USB-C/DP to DisplayPort 1.4 cable, I get and use the same options. However, when connected this way, it frequently doesn't wake up when the system wakes up, so I prefer the HDMI option.
HDR never shows up.
My left monitor is the ViewSonic VP2786 (4K60, HDR, AdobeRGB). It has USB-C/DP, DisplayPort, and HDMI inputs.
When I connect it with a USB-C/DP to DisplayPort 1.4 cable, I get and set all the same options as above, but I do get an HDR option. However, when I turn it on, I get a very washed out display - not HDR. When playing HDR content, I still get the usual dirty contrast areas where the brightness saturates non-HDR colorspaces and gets clipped.
When I connect it with the native USB-C connector (with a thunderbolt-compatible cable) I get the same as above, but as with the previous one it often fails to wake when the system wakes.
How do I get it to recognize and properly output HDR? How do I figure out why it's not working in the first place?
Some other notes:

This behavior was the same on 15.0 and 15.0.1.
When it "fails to wake", OS X agrees and has moved all of my windows/spaces to the other monitor. When I power-cycle the monitor OS X will then move all my windows/spaces back to where they were across the extended displays.

System Profiler display info:
  Chipset Model:    Apple M2 Max
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  Total Number of Cores:    30
  Vendor:   Apple (0x106b)
  Metal Support:    Metal 3
  Displays:
VP2786-4K:
  Resolution:   3840 x 2160 (2160p/4K UHD 1 - Ultra High Definition)
  UI Looks like:    3840 x 2160 @ 60.00Hz
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported
VP2785 SERIES:
  Resolution:   3840 x 2160 (2160p/4K UHD 1 - Ultra High Definition)
  UI Looks like:    3840 x 2160 @ 60.00Hz
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Rotation: Supported

